# how to make a script converting to radians the degree,seconds,minutes?

Tags: python, seconds, degrees, radians, minute

I am using python and I am having trouble making a script converting an angle with the degree,minutes,seconds given in radiant.

I already tried a few things but I am pretty new so I need help

Comment: Show us what you've tried already so SO can see where you're having trouble.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [mcve], [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what OP is looking for:

```
import Math as math

radians = "whatever number you want to use in here"
totalSeconds = int(round(radians * 360 * 60 * 60 / (2 * (math.pi)));
seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
degrees = totalSeconds / (60 * 60);
```

[Asin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) returns the arc sine of x, in radians. We also know that there is 2pi radians in a circle. There are 360 degrees in a circle, 60 minutes in a degree, and 60 seconds in a minute.Thus we have 360*60*60 seconds in a circle divided 2 pi to get us the total seconds. After that we can build backwards to get the total minutes and degrees.